# How to get blinking play button on top of the video in Adobe Premier Pro?

Tags: premiere, adobe, premiere-elements

I have added date and "Play ►" text but how do I get Play button "►" to flash like in the GIF below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a text editor and find the ▶︎ unicode symbol.
It will be called something like:

```
BLACK RIGHT-POINTING TRIANGLE
Unicode: U+25B6 U+FE0E, UTF-8: E2 96 B6 EF B8 8E
```

Open a sequence in premiere and create a text object.

Keyframe the opacity to 100%

Move forward 15 frames

Keyframe the opaticty to 0%

Select the two keyframes

Right click them and set them to "hold"

Copy both keyframes and paste them many times across your timeline.

[image: screengrab]